# How to get lines until an empty newline

Tags: regex

I want to get a bloc of lines which contains < or > operator until an empty newline

i try with this regex `.*[<>][^,\r\n]+?\(.*\S.*,.*\S.*\).*(?:(\n).*)`

You find here my example : https://regex101.com/r/UQYLB5/1/

Expected Result :

```
MATCH 1 : 
BAR18>17M(3,5.2)V 

MATCH 2 : 
BAR19>1.243037M(3,5.2)V 
INFORMATION PROCESS
TAKE B/F: 19V[1]
LIGHT PC CARD: 

MATCH 3 :
TEFAL17>1.262259M(4.5,5.5)V 
SISS17 : 1789-ID
LIGHT 19/17
MAPPING NICE :

MATCH 4 : 
MASCARPONE19>493.818969M(3,5.2)V 
BATA17 : CDER78945 -- 1875
LEFT ERREUR - CAME BACK 

MATCH 5 :
REPAR_178>748.515487M(4.5,5.5)V 
CHAN1 / STEREO MIX
```

Comment: Try `^\w+>.*(?:\n.+)*`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uAEU1o/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to match lines which could consist of spaces only, you could use match either `<` or `>` and match at least a non whitespace char `\S` in the following lines:

```
^[^<>\r\n]*[<>].*(?:\r?\n[^\r\n\S]*\S.*)*
```

The pattern will match:

- `^` Start of string
- `[^<>\r\n]*` Match any char except `<` `
- `[<>].*` Match either `<` or `>` and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `[^\r\n\S]*` Match any char except a newline
  - `\S.*` Match a non whitespace char and the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the group and repeat 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Blrjuo/1)

If the first line should also contain a `,` after matching `<` or `>`:

```
^[^<>\r\n]*[<>][^\r\n,]*,.*(?:\r?\n[^\r\n\S]*\S.*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mwYeR7/1)